# Creating n samples from multiple datasets in SAS

Tags: random, sas, sampling

I have 6 datasets, `x201201,x201202,...` and I'm looking for a way to make a random sample `n=200`, taken from the 6 datasets.

I have been looking at proc surveyselect, but it only takes one dataset. I could make a temp set merging the 6 sets, but is this the easiest/only way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create a copy. You can genearete a view.

```
data x2012 / view=x2012;
    set x201201 x201202 x201203 x201204 x201205 x201206;
run;

proc surveyselect data=x2012 method=srs n=200 out=SampleSRS;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was what i ended up using anyways, just thought the was a easier way :-)